# I want Google Docs embeddable PDF viewer not to display "open external" link

Tags: javascript, jquery, pdf, google-docs, google-docs-api

I am making a pdf viewer using google doc viewer. I am facing an issue. I don't want the user to download the pdf. If user clicks open external button, an external application is opened and pdf can be viewed. I don't want that button. What can I do?

Please see the attached image.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `rm=minimal` to the URL and you will scale of features from your viewer.

Here is an example **with** `rm=minimal` in the URL:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1byEvnxDkjQ49GNqRldHJyBrptlibFVItO_eneLypWic/edit?rm=minimal#gid=0

[image]

And here is an example **without** `rm=minimal` in the URL:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1byEvnxDkjQ49GNqRldHJyBrptlibFVItO_eneLypWic/edit#gid=0

[image]

I think that what you can´t remove with rm=minimal can´t be removed unfortunately.

**Update**
If rm-minimal can´t scale of what you want you could try to remove the element by jQuery with:
`$(".ndfHFb-c4YZDc-Wrql6b-SmKAyb").remove();` or by `CSS: .css('display','none')`

Comment: I added this code but the open external button is still displaying.

Comment: @AliZia can you share a link to your document and I´ll take a look at it.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/viewerng/viewer?url=http://istudy.com.pk/assets/3f05cc5ff16a157b57338f1262aeb0ae/1470400497d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e.pdf

Comment: @AliZia, what browser do you use? I don´t get that external button were you get it I get it in the toolbar... And I think that what you can´t remove with `rm=minimal` can´t be removed unfortunately.

Comment: Bro I am using the google doc pdf viewer plugin.. I am embedding it in my phone application.

Comment: Ok, then I´ll stick with my comment above "I think that what you can´t remove with rm=minimal can´t be removed unfortunately".

Comment: any way to remove it via css or jquery?

Comment: @AliZia, I´m not a jQuery guru but when I inspect the top row I get a class name called `ndfHFb-c4YZDc-Wrql6b-SmKAyb` you can either remove the entire row by doing `$(".ndfHFb-c4YZDc-Wrql6b-SmKAyb").remove();` I could not find a way to remove the button only... Regarding the class name for the top row, I don´t think it will change but I´m not 100% sure. But try it and see if it helps you.

Comment: Bro I already tried it. It hides temporarily. When I scroll pdf and go back to top, it appears again. :(

Comment: Try `.css('display','none')` instead.

Comment: @AliZia, did the above comment help you? Otherwise try the .hide() statement instead of .remove().